# RandomAccessFile not reading anything from file

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

When I try to read data with the same RandomAccessFile object nothing is returned, however when I create a
new Object and read that file it works fine, why is this occurring?

```
class RandomAccess{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(RandomAccessFile rand = new RandomAccessFile("random.txt","rw")){
        rand.writeInt(2);
        System.out.println(rand.readInt()); // this does not return anything
        //RandomAccessFile input = new RandomAccessFile("random.txt","rw");
        //System.out.println(input.readInt()); -> this correctly returns '2'
    }
    catch (IOException e){

    }

}
```

}

Comment: call rand.flush()

Comment: I though the print method auto flushed?

Comment: You don't call any type of `print` method on the random access file, and so your statement above does not make sense. Also, don't ignore exceptions.

Comment: But you're also reading from the same file after writing without resetting anything

Comment: Im calling print to see it in the console, it works fine with the commented code.